# Converting 'String' value from MySQL table into Interger

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing some script in attempt to **convert a `"String"` value, which is retrieved from a MySQL database table, into an `INTEGER`, which I will then use within my PHP code.**

The PHP Select-statement:

**Code:**

```
$my_number = "SELECT my_number from numbers_table where login = '".$_SESSION['login']."'";
$result_my_number = mysqli_query($conn,$my_number);

$converted_number = ($result_my_number + 20);     //  add 20 to my_number

echo $converted_number;
```

This results in nothing...

I done some research and attempted this:

**Code:**

```
$converted_number = ((int)$result_my_number) + 20;     //  convert my_number into an INTEGER
```

Also did not get any thing from this, neither a error message.

So I thought I would extract everything from the table, into an array:

**Code:**

```
$my_number = "SELECT * from numbers_table where login = '".$_SESSION['login']."'";
$result_my_number = mysqli_query($conn,$my_number);
$row_my_number = mysqli_fetch_array($result_my_number);

if ($row_my_number)  {
         $actual_number = $row_my_number['my_number']; 
          }

$final_number = ($actual_number + 20);   

echo $final_number;
```

And also did not get anything from this. Just a blank screen.

Comment: It might be helpful to try explicitly enable error reporting by adding `error_reporting( E_ALL ); ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );` to the top of your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `mysqli_fetch_row()` to get the number from the database.

```
$my_number = "SELECT my_number from numbers_table where login = '".$_SESSION['login']."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$my_number);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

$result_my_number = $row['my_number'];

$converted_number = ($result_my_number + 20);     //  add 20 to my_number

echo $converted_number;
```